# can't get jquery parentsUntil to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to use the jquery parentsUntil method to hide a button until a radio box is selected, but I can't seem to get it to work. It's probably something obvious, but it's been bugging me for a couple of days now. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.

```js
 (function($) {
 $(function(){
   $('.last-item').change(function() {
     if( $(this).val() != '' ) {
       $(this).parentsUntil('.step').find('.button-next').removeClass('hide');   
       $(this).parentsUntil('.step').find('.button-next').addClass('show');   
       console.log("changing the last item");
     }

   });

 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="step">
 <h1>Step 3 - Personal</h1>                    
   <div class="input-wrapper radio no-feedback">
     <div class="row no-gutter content-position-outer">
       <div class="col-md-6 content-center-inner">
         <label for="gender">What gender are you? <sup>*</sup></label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 content-center-inner">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
             <label class="radio-sex" for="gender_male">
               <input class="sr-only last-item" type="radio" placeholder="Male" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender_male" required="required" />
               <div class="radio-img radio-img-sex-male"></div>
                                            Male
                                        </label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-5">
             <label class="radio-sex" for="gender_female">
               <input class="sr-only last-item" type="radio" placeholder="Female" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender_female" required="required" />
               <div class="radio-img radio-img-sex-female"></div>
                                            Female
             </label>
           </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <a href="" class="button-prev" data-progress="2" data-step="step-2">Previous</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-6">
       <a href="" class="button-next hide" data-progress="4" data-step="step-4">Next</a>
     </div>
   </div>            
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mackecm2/rxyd9a3y/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good sensible answers, guys, but none of them worked for me. In the end I had to use

$(this).closest('.step-3').find('.button-next').css('display','block');

Answer (score 4):

[`.parentsUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) gets "the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to **but not including** the element matched by the selector,".

Try [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead

Answer (score 1):

This is likely what you meant?

No need to hide if value is empty since you cannot deselect a radio.

If you want to hide when some value is empty, use `.toggle($(this).val()!="")`

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.last-item').on("click",function() { // click assumes radio as last item 
      $(this).closest("div.step").find('.button-next').show(); 
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.button-next { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step">
  <h1>Step 3 - Personal</h1> 
  <div class="input-wrapper radio no-feedback">
    <div class="row no-gutter content-position-outer">
      <div class="col-md-6 content-center-inner">
        <label for="gender">What gender are you? <sup>*</sup>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 content-center-inner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
            <label class="radio-sex" for="gender_male">
              <input class="sr-only last-item" type="radio" placeholder="Male" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender_male" required="required" />
              <div class="radio-img radio-img-sex-male"></div>
              Male
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="radio-sex" for="gender_female">
              <input class="sr-only last-item" type="radio" placeholder="Female" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender_female" required="required" />
              <div class="radio-img radio-img-sex-female"></div>
              Female
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="" class="button-prev" data-progress="2" data-step="step-2">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-6">
      <a href="" class="button-next hide" data-progress="4" data-step="step-4">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I hope it will work

Note:remove hide class from -> class="button-next hide"

```
 $(function(){ 
   $('.button-next').hide();
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
            $('.button-next').show();           
       }

       else {
            $('.button-next').hide();   
       }
   });

 });
```